# Prove all large enough $N$ can add to 4 or more primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

It's hard to summarize this in the title, but my question is:

For all positive integral $N \geq M$ for some undetermined constant $M$, are there always at least four distinct naturals $k_1,..., k_4<N$ such that all four of $N+k_1, ..., N+k_4$ are prime?

I wanted to prove this by proving that there are at least 4 primes in the set $[N,2N-1]$, but the few established results I could find about prime gaps didn't seem to help much. I expect I'm missing something relatively basic given that it seems a very easy to do for any particular instance in practice, I just can't prove the general case

Additionally, this is part of a larger problem I'm trying to solve where the value of $M$ becomes relevant, so it'd be helpful to know what if any condition the result implies about it, but it's not necessary to answer. For the purposes of this question, it can be considered as large as needed.

Comment: This was first proved by Chebyshev in his _Mémoire sur les nombres premiers_. (He didn't do it explicitly for four primes, but it's evident from his inequalities that for every $k$ there is an $x_0$ such that $\pi(2x) - \pi(x) > k$ for all $x \geqslant x_0$ [and much more], and one can explicitly compute such an $x_0$ from them.) The prime number theorem implies $\pi(2x) - \pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\log x}$, which also gives much more than you ask for [but to get an explicit $M$ you need explicit bounds].

Comment: Proofs of Bertrand's postulate can often be modified easily to prove that for all sufficiently large $N$ there are more than $k$ primes between $N$ and $2N$. Then one can manually [or, with a simple computer programme] check for the minimal $M$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I can't quite grasp whether the PNT gives me concrete bound of some sort, and it's entirely monotonic, so I'm not very sure how I could tell that I have actually found my M on that basis. (although I see that it implies that _some_ value will _eventually_ work, but how would I know that I'd found it?)

Comment: Not entirely monotonic, that should say. If it were then I could assume the first example were it was true was M

Comment: If you have an explicit error bound in the PNT, then you can get a concrete $M$ from that. There are various explicit bounds by e.g. Rosser-Schoenfeld, Dusart, Axler. I'm not sure how useful an $M$ you get from those. Shouldn't be too bad, though. In any case, from Chebyshev's bounds one can get reasonable $M$, and the modern bounds should do rather better than worse.

Answer (score 1):

With help from the comments pointing me in the right direction, I *think* I have found that the answer to my question is given by the [Ramanujan primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime). Since the sequence $R_n$ is defined as the least prime for which $\pi(x)-\pi(\frac{x}{2}) \ge n$ for all $x>R_n$, then the value $M$ is $\lceil \frac{R_4}{2}\rceil=15$

(Unfortunately, I discovered the theorem I was invoking to *use* this fact didn't say what I thought it did and this doesn't actually help me, oops)